3d renderer - points act weird when behind camera
I am developing a 3d renderer in scratch and immediately ran into a problem where if a z is negative (my camera faces positive z) it's rendering gets all messed up. I continued to develop the project adding triangles, proper camera movement, and rotation but now this issue is really bugging me. My current projection equations are:
X Projected: $X / Z * FocalLength$
Y Projected: $Y / Z * FocalLength$

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

Are the points with negative Z in front of camera plane? Or on the back? It sound like you need "Z-clipping" i.e., remove geometry behind camers plane. You should also have XY clipping, otherwise you might be drawing things outside allocated screen's memory buffer

I'm using turbowarp so I don't need to worry about buffers (but that may be helpful for a future project). I have uploaded a live version here: https://crossscardev.github.io/3d%20Renderer.html
